# passing parameters to unmanaged C api from vb.net

Tags: c, vb.net, dll, parameters, unmanaged

I need to call a function in an unmanaged .dll written in C lang from vb.net. The function declaration looks like this

LONG _stdcall ReadInfo(char *reply);

Now the behavior of this function is that it copies some data in argument "reply" and returns a numeric value which signals its pass/fail status. How do i pass it a string object so that it can copy data. Following is how i access this function.

Dim str as String
obj.ReadDeviceInfo(str)

and the library is accessed this way...

```
Public Declare Auto Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal libFilePath As String) As Integer

Public Declare Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ModuleHandle As Integer, ByVal ProcName As String) As Integer

Public Declare Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ModuleHandle As Integer) As Integer


Public Function ReadDeviceInfo(ByRef reply As String) As Integer

    Dim MethodPointer As Integer
    MethodPointer = GetProcAddress(ModuleHandle, "ReadInfo")
    Dim deviceInfo As ReadInfo = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(MethodPointer, GetType(ReadInfo))
    Return deviceInfo.DynamicInvoke(reply)

End Function
```

When the call completes, returned status is absolutely fine but there is nothing in string "str". What is it that i am missing. I'm not sure about the string object that i am passing as argument. Any thoughts...

Comment: What is the "data" returned in argument "reply"? Is it a string? I'm asking because lazy C programmers occasionally use char* as a general purpose pointer variable that could point to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in .NET are immutable. Try passing a StringBuilder:

```
Public Function ReadDeviceInfo(ByRef reply As String) As Integer    
    ...

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(1000)
    result = deviceInfo.DynamicInvoke(sb)

    reply = sb.ToString()
    Return result
End Function
```

From [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx):

> If the string parameter can be input
>   and/or output, then use the
>   System.StringBuilder type. The
>   StringBuilder type is a useful class
>   library type that helps you build
>   strings efficiently, and it happens to
>   be great for passing buffers to native
>   functions that the functions fill with
>   string data on your behalf. Once the
>   function call has returned, you need
>   only call ToString on the
>   StringBuilder object to get a String
>   object.

Alternatively, pin a character array and pass its IntPtr.

Comment: Thanks Franks, StringBuilder threw exception. This is how tried 2nd approach.
        Dim pnt As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2000)
        ret = obj.ReadDeviceInfo(pnt)

Private Delegate Function ReadInfo(ByRef reply As IntPtr) As Integer

Public Function ReadDeviceInfo(ByRef reply As IntPtr) As Integer

        Dim MethodPointer As Integer
        MethodPointer = GetProcAddress(ModuleHandle, "ReadInfo")
        Dim deviceInfo As ReadInfo = Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(MethodPointer, GetType(ReadInfo))
        Return deviceInfo.DynamicInvoke(reply)

    End Function

Comment: You have to initialize the StringBuilder, use the constructor that takes the capacity.

Comment: @nobugz: still didn't work with capacity initialization. My test case simply breaks, no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://www.codeplex.com/clrinterop/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=14120) to automatically convert the C function into PInvoke declarations.

If you have a more detailed definition in C of the "data" that is returned, put that into PInvoke Assistant also. It can convert structure definitions, for example.

Answer (score 0):

These well-used functions demonstrate how to convert a string to a byte array, and pass it to a managed c++ function as a pinned IntPtr:

```
Public Function b_fromString(ByRef str As String) As Byte()
    If Not str Is Nothing Then
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length)
    Else
        Return New Byte() {}
    End If
End Function

Public Function cString(ByRef theString As String) As IntPtr
    Dim GC As System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(b_fromString(theString & Chr(0)), System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned)
    Dim ret As IntPtr = GC.AddrOfPinnedObject
    GC.Free()
    Return ret
End Function
```

This style of function can be used in a managed c++ wrapper:

```
long libinterface::loadData(System::IntPtr bytes, long length)
{   return lib->functionName((char*)bytes.ToPointer(), length);
}
```

String length is usually optional when using a null-terminated string. Useful, if not perfect.

Submitted for reference.

extra - uploading other arrays and bitmaps:

```
    Public Sub New(ByRef _obj As Array, ByRef read As Boolean, ByRef write As Boolean)
        Me.size = Marshal.SizeOf(_obj(0))
        Me.count = _obj.LongLength
        Me.ptr = GCHandle.Alloc(_obj, GCHandleType.Pinned)
        Me.id = lib.addBuffer(count * size, read, write, ptr.AddrOfPinnedObject)
    End Sub

    Public Function getimgPtr(ByRef img As Bitmap) As IntPtr
        Dim f As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = img.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, img.Width, img.Height), Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, img.PixelFormat)
        getimgPtr = f.Scan0
        img.UnlockBits(f)
    End Function
```